# Is it possible to create a shared RAM pool for multiple aws ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, orchestration

There are *n* ec2 instances serving webapps which do some heavyweight in-memory computations from time to time. The instances are stateful (user bound), always up providing other lightweight tasks and the computations are user requested so quick response time is important.

Is there a possibility to create a shared RAM pool for those instances so a heavyweight computation can start right away without any autoscaling routines?

The goal is to make this setup cost-efficient (so you don't need to pay for large instances using <5% of their capacity most of the time) and responsive (so a heavyweight computation can be handled immediately).

An alternative approach is also welcome.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You could use Lambda functions as long as 3GB memory is enough for your largest calculation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: Is there some way you can offload the computation (or the results) to ElastiCache?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this won't do